# Всплывающее окно на время

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет.

Имеется всплывающее окно, по клику оно закрывается, но не могу сделать, чтобы оно автоматически закрывалось через какое-то время. Кто знает, подскажите.

```
<a class="clickMe"href="#">хочу чтоб по клику открылось окно</a>
<div class="overlay" title="окно"></div>
<div class="popup">
<div class="close_order">x</div>
    <p>Тут будет текст</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.popup .close_order, .overlay').click(function (){
            $('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity','0');
            $('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility','hidden');
        });
        $('a.clickMe').click(function (e){
            $('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
            $('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Попробовал так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.popup .close_order, .overlay').click(function (){
                    $('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity','0');
                    $('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility','hidden');
                });
                $('a.clickMe').click(function (e){
                    $('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
                    $('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setTimeout(function() {$(".overlay, .popup").fadeOut()}, 3000)
                });
            });
```

Закрывает, но повторно нажав на ссылку, ничего не открывается(

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
        -o-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 323px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    border-radius: 11px;
}
.popup .close_order {
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 9px 4px 9px;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'tahoma', sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#3d51c8), to(#051fb8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background-color: #3d51c8;
    border: 1px solid #061fb8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.popup .close_order:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#051fb8), to(#3d51c8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5f0, #3d51c87);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background-color: #051fb8;
    border: 1px solid #00385E;
}
.popup .close_order:active {
    background: #8f9be0;
}.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
        -o-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 323px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    border-radius: 11px;
}
.popup .close_order {
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 9px 4px 9px;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'tahoma', sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#3d51c8), to(#051fb8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3d51c8, #051fb8);
    background-color: #3d51c8;
    border: 1px solid #061fb8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.popup .close_order:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#051fb8), to(#3d51c8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5f0, #3d51c87);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #051fb8, #3d51c8);
    background-color: #051fb8;
    border: 1px solid #00385E;
}
.popup .close_order:active {
    background: #8f9be0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не пойму, а зачем вы показываете всплывающее окно, а через 3 секунды скрываете? Если я правильно вас понял, то попробуйте весь код внутри обработчика a.clickMe обернуть в setTimeout.

Comment: @andreyqin, немного не понял, можете показать. Это у меня уведомление о том, что товар добавлен в корзину)
__

@Deonis, не успел сказать, а почему при нажатии на добавить в корзину товар не добавляется, а сразу открывается окно, может, нужна задержка перед открытием, без окна все хорошо было). Прошу извинить, что здесь написал, там уже закрыто.

Comment: @DimasikYES, я не знаю, как вы добавляете в корзину, где храните данные (*cookie, LocalStorage, etc.*) но ясное дело, что нужно проверить для начала, добавился товар или нет, а уж потом сигнализировать.

Comment: @Deonis, попробую. Для начала сделаю проверку. Спасибо:)

Comment: @Deonis, Добрый день. Все таки задал вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста:)
http://hashcode.ru/questions/360924/php-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83
____

@Deonis, спасибо, только вот при обновлении страницы уведомление Ваше о том, что товар добавлен, сразу выскакивает без нажатия на кнопку. Проверьте, пожалуйста, может что-то там не так.

Comment: @DimasikYES, всё правильно. При обновлении страницы (F5), идет повторная отправка последнего запроса.

Comment: @Deonis, а как запретить? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/00douut8/):

```
var popup = $('.popup'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    timer;
overlay.add($('.close_order',popup)).click(hidePopup);
$('a.clickMe').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    popup.add(overlay).finish().fadeIn(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(hidePopup, 3000);
    });
});
function hidePopup(){
    return popup.add(overlay).fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: @Deonis, большое спасибо!:)
__

@Deonis, вот только не работает с моими стилями почему-то. Выше разместил, если что css.

Comment: @DimasikYES, поубирайте везде из css opacity и visibility, transition: opacity - тоже ни к чему для такого варианта. Для оверлея и модального окна, изначально в css:

    .overlay, .popup {
      display: none;
    }

Comment: @Deonis, вообщем я убрал, теперь окно появляется сразу, как обновишь страницу. Это из-за того, что убрал opacity: 0;, а с ними не работает тоже.

Comment: @DimasikYES, Вы задали по умолчанию display: none; для .overlay и  .popup?

Comment: @Deonis, да.

Comment: @DimasikYES, значит где-то у вас еще прописано свойство **display**, которое перекрывает нужное. В конце концов, если уж не можете разобраться, то напишите в JS:

    var popup = $('.popup').hide(),
        overlay = $('.overlay').hide(),
        timer;

Comment: @Deonis, все исправил, там было 2 класса .popup, во втором не заметил. Спасибо большое. Не успел сказать, а почему при нажатии на добавить в корзину, товар не добавляется, а сразу открывается окно, может, нужна задержка перед открытием, без окна все хорошо было)

Comment: @DimasikYES, ответить всё-равно успел, но то что у вас по нескольку раз свойства классу прописываются - это жёстко )) Видать, чтоб наверняка сработало ;)

**UPD** Я не знаю, как вы добавляете в корзину, где храните данные (*cookie, LocalStorage, etc.*) но ясное дело, что нужно проверяить для начала - добавился товар или нет, а уж потом сигнализировать.